# Puppeteer Launch Incognito

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, incognito-mode

I am connected to a browser using a ws endpoint (`puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: '' })`).

When I launch the browser that I ultimately connect to, is there a way to launch this in incognito?

I know I can do something like this:

```
const incognito = await this.browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
```

But it seems like the incognito session is tied to the originally opened browser. I just want it to be by itself.

I also see you can do this:

```
const baseOptions: LaunchOptions = { args: ['--incognito']};
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way or not.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The best way to accomplish your goal is to launch the [browser](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-browser) directly into incognito mode by passing the [`--incognito`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#incognito) flag to [`puppeteer.launch()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--incognito',
  ],
});
```

Alternatively, you can create a new incognito [browser context](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-browsercontext) after launching the browser using [`browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browsercreateincognitobrowsercontext):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
```

You can check whether a browser context is incognito using [`browserContext.isIncognito()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browsercontextisincognito):

```
if (context.isIncognito()) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: When the browser is launched in `--incognito` mode, the `newPage()` still share the data and not incognito. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 35):

the solutions above didn't work for me:

an incognito window is created, but then when the new page is created, it is no longer incognito.

The solution that worked for me was:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const page = await context.newPage();
```

then you can use page and it's an incognito page

Comment: It's true. Run puppeteer without headless and see for yourselves. Pages are not incognito in the other answers

Comment: It worked here! Although the incognito window was not black, which was causing me confusion at first sigh, but it was indeed the chromium incognito window

Answer (score -1):

For Puppeteer sharp it's rather messy but this seems to work.. Hopefully it helps someone.

```
using (Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options))
{
     // create the async context 
    var context = await browser.CreateIncognitoBrowserContextAsync();

    // get the page created by default when launch async ran and close it whilst keeping the browser active
    var browserPages = await browser.PagesAsync();
    await browserPages[0].CloseAsync();

    // create a new page using the incognito context
    using (Page page = await context.NewPageAsync())
    {
        // do something 
    }
}
```