# Puppeteer: How to set the default browser context to incognito?

Tags: puppeteer

I am attempting to launch a Chrome browser in incognito mode with the code below. When I create a new page and navigate to a URL, **I would like there to be one instance of the Chrome browser and I would like that single Chrome browser instance to be incognito.**

However, the issue I'm running into is that even though I pass in the `--incognito` flag to launch the browser, the default browser context thinks it is not incognito. To try to work around this, I have tried the two workarounds, denoted in the code by "Workaround 1" and "Workaround 2". Both of these fail to accomplish the bolded sentence of the paragraph above.

```
import { Page, Browser } from "puppeteer";

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {
    const browser: Browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: [ '--incognito' ], // Passing in the flag here
    });

    // Shockingly, the below logs FALSE!
    console.log(browser.defaultBrowserContext().isIncognito());

    // Workaround 1: This creates a new page in non-incognito mode, but I would like the new page to be in incognito mode.
    const browserPage: Page = await browser.newPage();
    browserPage.goto("https://www.google.com");

    // Workaround 2: This creates a new page in incognito mode, but I would like only one instance of the Chrome browser instead of two.
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const newContextPage: Page = await context.newPage();
    newContextPage.goto("https://www.amazon.com");
}

run();
```

Therefore, how can I accomplish these 2 items simultaneously?

1. A single Chrome browser instance is launched
2. That single Chrome browser instance is incognito

I think the answer is to set the default browser context to incognito, but how do I do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4400) it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED:**

You can try something like this, it will launch one chromium instance in incognito mode.

```
async function run() {
  const browser: Browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [ '--incognito' ], // Passing in the flag here
  });

  const [ browserPage ] = await browser.pages();
  await browserPage.goto("https://www.google.com");
}

run();
```

Alternatively, you can create a new incognito browser context after launching the browser using `browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()`:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
```

or

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const page = await context.newPage();
```

Comment: You can use `browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()` too.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, as said here: [Puppeteer Launch Incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068873/puppeteer-launch-incognito)

You can create a new incognito browser context after launching the browser using browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext():

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
```